# Alternate proofs of Quillen's theorem on formal group laws and MU

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is related to this posting:

[complex cobordism from formal group laws?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5166/complex-cobordism-from-formal-group-laws)

but not entirely the same.  I'd like to know if there are any proofs of Quillen's theorem that $\pi_* (MU)$ is the Lazard ring (home of the universal formal group law) other than Quillen's.  Specifically, is it possible to prove the result without a deep understanding of the structure of $H^*(MU)$ as a module over the Steenrod algebra?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. I thought Quillen's proof (in his "Elementary proofs..." article) was notable in that it does not use the Steenrod algebra, Adams spectral sequences, and so on?  

Comment: Thanks, Mark, this is very helpful; I was unaware of this proof (and was really only thinking of Milnor's computation of $\pi_* MU$ using the Adams SS).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quillen's proof of this in the paper

*Elementary proofs of some results of cobordism theory using Steenrod operations*. Advances in Math. 7 1971 29–56 (1971)

does not make use of Adams spectral sequences or the structure of $H^\ast(MU)$ over the Steenrod algebra. In fact the only result from homotopy which is assumed is that the groups $MU^\ast(X)$ are finitely generated in each dimension.

Answer (score 4):

Jacob Lurie taught a course at Harvard in the spring of 2010 which included a slick proof of Quillen's theorem. I'm pretty sure Steenrod operations are not mentioned at all. The course page is [here](http://math.harvard.edu/~lurie/252x.html), and the notes which include this proof are in [lecture 7](http://math.harvard.edu/~lurie/252xnotes/Lecture7.pdf). Also, the proof of Lazard's theorem (on the structure of the Lazard ring) in lectures 2 and 3 is very cool.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for linking to these notes! However, it seems what is proved in lecture 7 is that the map $L\to \pi_\ast(MU)$ classifying the formal group law of complex cobordism is a *rational* isomorphism (this is indeed very nice, using just the Hurewicz homomorphism). Then Adams spectral sequence arguments are used in subsequent lectures to prove the result at each prime.